# Folks theorem for hypercube: In high dimension, everyone is alone (the curse of dimensionality)

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, reference-request

I'm reading a slide on dimensionality curse

[image]

I've searched on Google, but can not find any reference for this Folks theorem. Could you please suggest me some of them?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality where the reference given is a 1957 book by R. Bellman.

Comment: @JeanMarie I've just looked at the book and could not find the Folks theorem.

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm not sure about that. I just take that name from the slide. I tried to search in the book with "hypercube", but to no avail.

Comment: Oh, I see. "Folk" is with the meaning "common point of view/knowledge, whose origin is impossible or uninteresting to find out". This word takes its origin in "Folklore" (traditions, etc.)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your interest in my question.

Comment: @JeanMarie My professor has provided me with the original paper. See my below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My professor has provided with the paper containing the theorem. It's [On the Surprising Behavior of Distance Metrics in High Dimensional Space](https://bib.dbvis.de/uploadedFiles/155.pdf) by Charu C. Aggarwal, Alexander Hinneburg, and Daniel A. Keim.